# Array.binarysearch in java

Tags: java

Given:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Quest 
{ 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
  String[] colors = {"blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "orange"}; 
  Arrays.sort(colors); 
   int s2 = Arrays.binarySearch(colors, "orange"); 
   int s3 = Arrays.binarySearch(colors, "violet"); 
    System.out.println(s2 + " " + s3);
}
}
```

The output is `2 -5`. Why?

Comment: Have you considered reading the Javadoc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2 is the index of orange in the sorted array (so it is the third element).

-5 is -insertion_point - 1.  The insertion point is where the key could be inserted and the array remain sorted.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int[], int)

Comment: I am unable to get why -5 is comming

Comment: Read the docs.  Sorted is: "blue", "green", "orange", "red", "yellow".  If you were going to insert "violet" into that and keep the array sorted, where would you put it? Before yellow.  What is yellow's index 4.  What is -4 -1? -5.

Answer (score 4):

The (new) sorted array looks like that:

```
 0       1        2         3      4
"blue", "green", "orange", "red", "yellow"
```

- the first result `2` is the index of element `"orange"`
- the second result is <strike>.. *strange*, should be negative. Please verify your results.</strike> the result of the equation `(-4 - 1) = -5` The insertion point for `"violet"` would be at index `4` (behind `"red"`)

**Further Reading**

- [Arrays.binarySearch - javaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29)